# get-winevent: Property Field filled with System.String[] after removing descriptional content parts

Tags: powershell, get-winevent

I'm trying to filter event-logs, which works fine except for the message field within the query. The message field has a lot of descriptive text in it. I only want the first sentence of it, because this is the important one, the rest is garbage.

Example content of a message-field:

```
An account was successfully logged on.

Subject:
    Security ID:  SYSTEM
    Account Name:  WIN-R9H529RIO4Y$
    Account Domain:  WORKGROUP
    Logon ID:  0x3e7
Logon Type:10
New Logon:
       Security ID:  WIN-R9H529RIO4Y\Administrator
    Account Name:  Administrator
    Account Domain:  WIN-R9H529RIO4Y
    Logon ID:  0x19f4c
    Logon GUID:  {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
Process Information:
   Process ID:  0x4c0
    Process Name:  C:\Windows\System32\winlogon.exe
Network Information:
     Workstation Name: WIN-R9H529RIO4Y
    Source Network Address: 10.42.42.211
    Source Port:  1181
Detailed Authentication Information:
     Logon Process:  User32 
    Authentication Package: Negotiate
    Transited Services: -
   Package Name (NTLM only): -
   Key Length:  0

This event is generated when a logon session is created. It is generated on the computer that was accessed.

The subject fields indicate the account on the local system which requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or Services.exe.

The logon type field indicates the kind of logon that occurred. The most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).

The New Logon fields indicate the account for whom the new logon was created, i.e. the account that was logged on.

The network fields indicate where a remote logon request originated. Workstation name is not always available and may be left blank in some cases.

The authentication information fields provide detailed information about this specific logon request.


The authentication information fields provide detailed information about this specific logon request.
•Logon GUID is a unique identifier that can be used to correlate this event with a KDC event.
•Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.
•Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM protocols.
•Key length indicates the length of the generated session key. This will be 0 if no session key was requested.
```

I only want "An account was successfully logged on."

What I've tried already (and failed):

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path="c:\temp\export.evtx";} |
    Where-Object {($_.id -eq "4624" -and $_.properties[8].value -in 2,3,10) -or ($_.id -eq "4625") -or ($_.id -eq "4800")} |
        ForEach-Object{
            $SelectorStrings = [string[]]@(
            'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="TargetUserName"]',
            'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="TargetDomainName"]',
            'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="TargetLogonId"]',
            'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="LogonType"]',
            'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="WorkstationName"]',
            'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="IpAddress"]',
            'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="IpPort"]'
            )
            $PropertySelector = [System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogPropertySelector]::new($SelectorStrings)

            $UserName,$Domain,$LogonId,$LogonType,$ComputerName,$IPAddress,$Port = $_.GetPropertyValues($PropertySelector)

            [PSCustomObject]@{
            TimeCreated  = $_.TimeCreated
            UserName     = $UserName
            Domain       = $Domain
            LogonId      = $LogonId
            LogonType    = $LogonType
            ComputerName = $ComputerName
            IPAddres     = $IPAddres
            Port         = $Port
            Message      = ($_.Message).split(".")       
            }|Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Force -Encoding UTF8 -Path 'c:\temp\exportencoding2.csv' -Append      
        }
```

The Result is:

```
"TimeCreated","UserName","Domain","LogonId","LogonType","ComputerName","IPAddres","Port","Message"
"04.12.2017 13:56:34","Testuser","lab.internal",,"7","AssetWin7PC","127.0.0.1","0","System.String[]"
```

The Output is "System.String[]" then but it should be the first sentence.

Comment: `($_.Message).split(".")` returns an array of strings. If you only want the first one, then I'd use `Message      = ($_.Message).split(".")[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***TL;DR***

`($_.Message).split(".")` returns an array of strings. If you only want the first one, then I'd use `Message = ($_.Message).split(".")[0]`

---

***More Info***

In your `[PSCustomObject]`, you say that "Message" should be `($_.Message).split(".")`.

This returns an array of strings e.g.

```
$Msg = "An account was successfully logged on.`r`nSubject blah blah blah"
($Msg.split(".")).GetType.FullName
```

[image]

*The open and close square brackets are a helpful, little reminder*

We can double check this by running the command and seeing that our single line is 3 lines now.

```
$Msg.split(".")
```

[image]

Since we know that you want the part before the first fullstop, we can specify that we want to return that part only.

```
$Msg.split(".")[0]
```

[image]

And this should work for us because we are returning a single, string object (*which we can check*)

```
($Msg.split(".")[0]).GetType().FullName
```

[image]

*No square brackets means 1 item*

---

***Your Code***

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
  TimeCreated  = $_.TimeCreated
  UserName     = $UserName
  Domain       = $Domain
  LogonId      = $LogonId
  LogonType    = $LogonType
  ComputerName = $ComputerName
  IPAddres     = $IPAddres
  Port         = $Port
  Message      = ($_.Message).split(".")[0]       
}
```

Comment: Very nice explanation. Thank you very much. I've learned a lot with your description @Shaneis

Comment: Glad it helped you out @PeterCore